# How to update data if array is empty?

Tags: php, arrays, logic

I want to update empty array .So I check is empty and want to update the original variable.So I tried by `&` but it doesn't change empty array `$array2` .I had tried many hours but not working!!!

```
<?php
$array1 = array('one','two','three');
$array2 = array();
$array3 = array ('four');
$array4 = array ('five','six');
check([&$array1,&$array2,&$array3,&$array4]);
function check($arr){   
    foreach ($arr as $k=>$value) {          
        if(empty($value)){      
            $arr[$k][] = "nothing";
            return $arr[$k];
        }
        else{
            return $arr[$k];
        }
    }
}
var_dump($array2); 
//actual output : empty
//expect output :  0 => string 'nothing'
?>
```

Comment: What is "original variable" in your script?

Comment: sorry, i mean $array2 because it is empty !

Comment: For one, your function will only ever check the first array and then `return`. Beyond that, pass-by-reference simply doesn't work like this. You'll have to rethink your approach.

Comment: `empty($value) == false` means that `$value` __is not empty__.

Comment: I got it ,Thanks @u_mulder

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:

```
<?php
$array1 = array('one','two','three');
$array2 = array();
$array3 = array ('four');
$array4 = array ('five','six');
list($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4) = check([$array1,$array2,$array3,$array4]);
function check($arr){   
    foreach ($arr as $k => $value) {          
        if(empty($value)){     
            $arr[$k] = "nothing";
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}
var_dump($array2); 
//actual output : string(7) "nothing"
//expect output :  string(7) "nothing"

?>
```

You've written your function very strangely, actually.

**UPDATE**. Output of other arrays instead of only one.

```
var_dump($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4);

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "one"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "two"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "three"
}
string(7) "nothing"
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "four"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "five"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "six"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? If you `var_dump` other arrays, you'll see them. I've added output to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look following code.

```
 $array1 = array('one','two','three');
 $array2 = array();
 $array3 = array ('four');
 $array4 = array ('five','six');
 $arr11=check([&$array1,&$array2,&$array3,&$array4]);
 function check($arr){  
    foreach ($arr as $k=>$value) {          
       print_r($value);
       if(empty($value)){     
          $arr[$k] = "nothing";
        }
        else{
           $arr[$k];
        }
     }
   return $arr;
 }

print_r($arr11);
var_dump($array2); 
//actual output : empty
//expect output :  0 => string 'nothing'
```

It will display following result.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => one
        [1] => two
        [2] => three
    )

[1] => nothing
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => four
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => five
        [1] => six
    )

)


string(7) "nothing"
```